# Begginer Tutorial Publisher/Subscriber Server/Client in C++ boost assertion failed

Tags: ros, boost, beginner-tutorials, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I run the beginner tutorials for publisher/suscriber or service/client I get the following error:

add_two_ints_server: /usr/include/boost/smart_ptr/shared_ptr.hpp:418: boost::shared_ptr::reference boost::shared_ptr::operator*() const [with T = boost::regex_traits_wrapperboost::regex_traits<char >; boost::shared_ptr::reference = boost::regex_traits_wrapperboost::regex_traits<char >&]: Assertion `px != 0' failed.
Aborted (core dumped)

It seems to me that the code is exactly the same as those in the tutorial, I am not sure if there is a configuration problem.

The files were made correctly by make.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/58117/begginer-tutorial-publisher/subscriber-server/client-in-c++-boost-assertion-failed/) by [Juan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4088/juan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 208 on 2013-03-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Oier](https://answers.ros.org/users/3642/oier/) on 2013-03-14**:
What Ubuntu and ROS version are you using?

**Comment by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) on 2013-03-14**:
Can you post the CMake file?

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-03-14**:
Are they exactly the same or do they just seem like that? You can easily check with tools like `meld` or `diffuse`. Looks like a pointer mistake for me.

**Comment by [Juan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4088/juan/) on 2013-03-14**:
Ubuntu1210/Groovy.

Added the following lines in CMake..
rosbuild_add_executable(talker src/talker.cpp)
rosbuild_add_executable(listener src/listener.cpp)
rosbuild_add_executable(add_two_ints_server src/add_two_ints_server.cpp)
rosbuild_add_executable(add_two_ints_client src/add_two_ints_client.cpp)

**Comment by [Juan](https://answers.ros.org/users/4088/juan/) on 2013-03-14**:
I tried running it in different ways and I am not sure sometimes no exceptions come along. I did notice however, a difference between the c++ produced code and python produced code.

In cpp pub/sub: [${severity}] [${time}]: ${message}
In python: INFO] [WallTime: 1363321815.771314] hello world 136

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am sorry Juan, I don't know how it works for groovy yet, but a similar error is caused in fuerte too, when you don't link boost libraries in CMakeLists.txt. Here is an example http://answers.ros.org/question/42853/how-to-solve-undefined-reference-to-symbol-boostsignalsconnectionconnection/

---

Originally posted by [yigit](https://answers.ros.org/users/2389/yigit/) with karma: 796 on 2013-03-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0